WinError 2 El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado whisper - Gradio
estaba intentando un codigo de un proyecto que utilizando gradio y whisper permitía traducir la voz, tengo un problema y es que al momento de capturar el audio desde gradio y enviarlo al whisper este me saca el error de "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado", y buscando la ruta el archivo si existe, ya he intentado formatear la ruta o pegar el archivo en un fichero permanente y aun asi sigue el error, este es el codigo:
import whisper as wh
from translate import Translator
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from elevenlabs import VoiceSettings
from elevenlabs.client import ElevenLabs
import os


ruta_env = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), ".env")

config = dotenv_values(ruta_env)
ELEVENLABS_API_KEY = config["ELEVENLABS_API_KEY"]


def traductor(file_audio):
    try:
        model = wh.load_model("base")
        resultado = model.transcribe(file_audio,lenguage="Spanish", fp16=False)
        traduccion = resultado["text"]
    except Exception as e:
        raise gr.Error(
            f"Se ha producido un error al momento de transcribir el texto: {str(e)}")
    
    try:
        traduccionIngles = Translator(from_lang="es", to_lang= "en").translate(traduccion)
    except Exception as e:
        raise gr.Error(
            f"Se ha producido un error al momento de traducir el texto: {str(e)}")
      
      
    try:
        clienteElevenlabs = ElevenLabs(api_key= ELEVENLABS_API_KEY)
        respuesta = clienteElevenlabs.text_to_speech.convert(
            voice_id="pNInz6obpgDQGcFmaJgB",  
            optimize_streaming_latency="0",
            output_format="mp3_22050_32",
            text=traduccionIngles,
            model_id="eleven_turbo_v2",  
            voice_settings=VoiceSettings(
                stability=0.0,
                similarity_boost=1.0,
                style=0.0,
                use_speaker_boost=True,
            ),
        )
        
        save_file_path = "audios/ingles.mp3"
        with open(save_file_path,"wb") as f:
            for chunk in respuesta:
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
    except Exception as e:
        raise gr.Error(
            f"Se ha producido un error al momento de mostrar el audio: {str(e)}")
        
          
    return save_file_path    
        
        
web = gr.Interface(
    fn = traductor,
    inputs = gr.Audio(
        sources=["upload"],
        type="filepath"
        ),
    outputs=[gr.Audio()],
    title= "Traductor de voz"
    )

web.launch() ```

